How can we extend the derivative (with respect to IC) of $\ddot x = \dot x^2 +x^3$ from small $t$ to large $t$?

Find the derivative with respect to $B$ for $B = 0$ of the solution of the equation $$\ddot x = \dot x^2 +x^3$$ with initial
conditions $$x(0) = 0 \\ \dot x(0) = B.$$
-- V. Arnold

A complete solution is here and here, though I am not familiar with their techniques and cannot understand how they're using them.  Nonetheless, before reading them, I was able to get the correct answer on my own -- though I only proved it in a small case.
My question is: Is my approach correct, or was it just lucky? How can it be augmented to cover the full case?
Solution:
The solution is $$\frac {dx}{dB} \Bigg |_{B=0} = t. $$
We consider $B$ and $t$ sufficiently close to $0$, so that $x$ is arbitrarily close to $0$, and $x^3 \ll \dot x^2$ to any desired degree.
We therefore approximate $$\ddot x \approx \dot x^2$$ with error going to zero as $t \to 0$, which is a separable ODE giving $$x \approx \log \frac{1}{1 - Bt}$$ for $t \approx 0$.  Differentiating with respect to $B$ gives the solution.
Since we are finding the derivative at $B = 0$, we need not consider larger $B$.  We do need to consider larger $t$ (at least until the solution goes to infinity, which will happen before $t = 1/B$). From the other solutions, it seems that the answer remains $t$, though I can't show why.

Update
We have $$\dddot x = \dot x (2 \ddot x + 3x^2) \\ \ddddot x = \ddot x (2 \ddot x + 3x^2) + \dot x (2 \dddot x + 6 x \dot x)$$ and similar equations for all higher order derivatives.  Evaluating each of these at $t=0$, we get the Taylor series: $$x = 0 + Bt + B^2t^2/2! + 2B^3t^3/3! + 6B^4t^4/4! + ...$$ so $$\frac{dx}{dB} = t + \mathcal{O}(t^2)\mathcal{O}(B^2)$$ which reduces to just $t$ whenever $t$ or $B$ is sufficiently close to zero.  My method above exploited this for all $B$ but only small $t$; the Taylor series shows the exact same expression works for small $B$ and all $t$.
The question remains: Is this just a coincidence? Can the simple method above for small $t$, all $B$, be applied to small $B$, all $t$? If so, how, and if not, why not?

Let
$$
x(t;B)=x_0(t)+Bx_1(t)+B^2x_2(t)+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B^nx_n(t). \tag{1}
$$
Using $x(0;B)=0$ gives
$$ x_0(0)=x_1(0)=x_2(0)=\cdots. $$
Using $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}x(0;B)=B$ gives
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B^nx_n'(0)=B $$
from which one obtains
$$ x'_0(0)=0,x_1'(0)=1,x_n'(0)=0, n=2,3,\cdots. $$
Putting (1) into the equation gives
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B^nx_n''(t)=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B^nx_n'(t))^2+(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B^nx_n(t))^3. \tag2$$
Comparing the coefficients of $1$ of (2) produces
$$ x''_0(t)=x_0'(t)+x_0^3(t). $$
By using $x_0(0)=x'_0(0)=0$ and the existence and uniqueness, one has $x_0(t)=0$.
Comparing the coefficients of $B$ from (2) produces
$$ x_1''(t)=0.$$
By using $x_1(0)=0,x_1'(0)=1$, one has $x_1(t)=t$. Comparing the coefficients of $B^2$ from (2) produces
$$ x_2''(t)=1.$$
By using $x_2(0)=0,x_2'(0)=0$, one has $x_2(t)=\frac12t^2$. So
$$ x(t;B)=Bt+\frac12B^2t^2+\cdots.$$
Thus your calculation is correct and not a coincidence.

Considering
$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 = x_2\\
\dot x_2 = x_1^3+x_2^2\\
x_1(0) = 0, x_2(0)=B
}\Rightarrow \cases{\dot x = f(x,B)\\ x_1(0) = 0, x_2(0)=B}
$$
as $\frac{\partial \dot x}{\partial B}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial B}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial B}$ we have the equivalent system
$$
\cases{
\dot x_1 = x_2\\
\dot x_2 = x_1^3+x_2^2\\
x_1(0) = 0\\
x_2(0) =B\\
\dot s_1 = s_2\\
\dot s_2 = 3 x_1^2s_1 + 2x_2s_2\\
s_1(0) = 0\\
s_2(0) = 1
}
$$
Here $s_i = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial B}$ so it is clear that for $|x|$ small we have  $s_1(t)\approx t$
